# Power series $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{(n!)^2}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

It is well known that $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{(n!)} = e^x$.

What is $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{(n!)^2}$ ?

Comment: I have no idea about this problem. This problem raises when I calculate an integral of the Bessel function.

Comment: Maybe it could be represented as some transcendental functions...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Closed form of series with factorial-squared denominator?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2466836/closed-form-of-series-with-factorial-squared-denominator) – found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum%5Climits_%7Bn%3D0%7D%5E%5Cinfty%20%5Cfrac%7Bx%5En%7D%7B(n!)%5E2%7D%24)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{(n!)^2}=I_0\left(2 \sqrt{x}\right)$$ where appears the modified Bessel function of the first kind.

Comment: Great thanks! I am a freshman to Bessel function, this qustion may seem silly to you!

Comment: @Muse_China. There is no silly question but there are silly answers ! Welcome to the fascinating world of Bessel functions !