# Simplification of multinomial like expression with squared coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

By the multinomial theorem we have that
$$(a + b + c)^n = \sum_{0 \leq i \leq j \leq n} \frac{n!}{i! (j-i)! (n-j)!} a^i b^{j-i} c^{n-j},$$
and so
$$\sum_{0 \leq i \leq j \leq n} \frac{1}{i! (j-i)! (n-j)!} a^i b^{j-i} c^{n-j} = \frac{1}{n!} (a+b+c)^n.$$
I am interested, however, in simplifying the summation given by
$$\sum_{0 \leq i \leq j \leq n} \left(\frac{1}{i! (j-i)! (n-j)!}\right)^2 a^i b^{j-i} c^{n-j}. \quad \quad (\dagger)$$
Due to the squared coefficients it now becomes a bit complicated to write the summation in terms of $(a+b+c)^n$... Is there a way to simplify the summation $(\dagger)$ in terms of powers of $n$? This summation also reminds me of a "tensorised version" of the terms in the power expansion of a [Bessel function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2466836/closed-form-of-series-with-factorial-squared-denominator). Do you see any possible simplifications? By any chance is there a name for this "multinomial like" expression with squared coefficients?

Comment: Do you only want the sum of coefficients, or an expression for the whole (including the varibles)?

Comment: @DS I'm looking for a simplification of the whole, including the variables

Comment: Any reason to believe this has a closed form?

Comment: No reason :( I just want to see whether I can simplify that summation further. Actually, let $S_n$ denote the sum $(\dagger)$ above. Ultimately I am interested in the series $S:= \sum_{n=0}^\infty S_n$ and whether I can write $S$ in a simpler form, e.g. as a summation over $n\in \mathbb{N}$ (eliminating the summations over $i$ and $j$).

Comment: Your $S$ will contain terms like $a^2bc$.

Comment: Indeed, $S_4$ has that term

Comment: First try finding the sum for $a=b=c=1$. Then you can move to arbitrary values of $a,b,c$.

Comment: That will be the sum of the coefficients for all $n$... I'm not trying to compute the sum. I'm trying to rewrite it as a sum over $n$ with the summations over $i$ and $j$ suppressed. Surely at the expense of using some other functions, like Bessel functions. Thanks for having a look though.